# select value not changing after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a piece of code to generate a chart by values generated by an ajax call.

The problem is, the select (years) is not changing its value after the call is done loading. The weird thing is, i can see its value changing (if i alert its current value) but it simply won't change.

The code:

http://pastebin.com/RNfLmdWy

The $.load_x function is a custom loader but it behaves the same as a regular $.getJson call.

Comment: So the only problem is that <select id="years"> value is not changed? How can you tell that the value hasn't change - by looking on the select, or by reading the select value with some code? I pasted your code on my local server and beside ajax call fails (404 code obviously), the select changes its value.

Comment: it changes to the default value after the ajax call

Comment: Ok - please paste example data that is returned by your load_x function so I can mock my local example and play around with it.

Comment: {"rows":{"8":"4","9":"4"},"records":2}

it also uses jqplot (http://www.jqplot.com/) and ofcourse jquery

Comment: I'm getting close here. I reproduced the error you were reporting. The select doesn't change its value because of **many** errors that pop-up in the firebug console, I'll investigate further. Which version of jqplot are you using?

Comment: Version: 1.0.0b2_r792. btw i use firebug as well.. i dont see those errors

Comment: Check my response and as for those errors I mentioned they're popping-up when I hover over chart one. But those don't affect the select issue as it turned out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! This part is responsible:

```
var option = $(this).attr('id').split('option_');
$('#'+option[1]).val(String($cur_val));
setTimeout(function(){$('#'+option[1]).val(String($cur_val))}, 1000);
```

I don't know what were you trying to do here, but basically, the option variable becomes a array ["", "years"], and in the next step you are setting $("#"+option[1]) value to $cur_val variable which is anything found in the #option_years input.

Soooo to wrap it up. To get rid of the "my select is not changing its value" issue in this case just *get rid of those lines* or at least let me know what you wanted to do there :)

EDIT: Here's the example that works for me: http://pastebin.com/sFRT3GJa (tested on FF and Chrome). As you can see it the source I use jQuery 1.6.1, jQuery UI 1.8.16 and jqPlot 1.0.0b2_r792. Other than that I've moved the callback function of $.load_x and named it *handleJSON*. Then I passed the JSON data you've pasted in your question to mock the successfull response of the $.load_x function.

Comment: It still doesnt work. Well at least not if i delete those lines. I created that because of the original problem. I wanted to save the value in an input and then set the select with that value. But it doesnt want to change and its breaking my balls :(

Comment: Impossible :) I left the working example at the office, I'll post it tomorrow - maybe I modified something else in the process. One thing is that I probably used jquery 1.6.1 not 1.4. Oh and one more thing - I moved the options div to div outside of #chart1 div (in your pasted code options is a child node of chart1 div).

Comment: Blast! Your comment there saved the day. Ill post the final code to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you make `get_port_graph` call, give some time for select box to change the dropdown since its heavy call. It will work.

```
function year_chart(year)
{
    settTimeout(function(){
        var d = new Date();
        get_port_graph("Uitporteringen "+year,d.getMonth(), year,'outport', 'chart1', 'bar');   
    }, 100);       

}
```